# Add extension with jFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm creating a program which will create files with different extensions. For that, i'm using the `JFileChooser`. I've set the `FileFilter` to accept only my desired extensions, but when I select one, I still have to add the extension in the name of the file myself. How can I solve that? Many thanks!

Comment: Add some code with the question, so that we can check where the problem is.

Comment: try {
            Save = new JFileChooser();
            int ReturnValue = Save.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (ReturnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                Base = Save.getSelectedFile();
                DB = new DatabaseBuilder(Base)
                        .setFileFormat(Database.FileFormat.V2010)
                        .create();
            }
        } catch (HeadlessException | IOException P) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + P);
            System.out.println("Error thrown: P");
        }

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to add the extension yourself after the user closes the dialog.

This example allows the user to specify a file ending with ".foo" or ".bar" and will add that extension if the user did not do so.

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
fileChooser.removeChoosableFileFilter(fileChooser.getAcceptAllFileFilter());
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Files ending in .foo", "foo"));
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Files ending in .bar", "bar"));


int option = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

  if (file!=null) {
    FileFilter fileFilter = fileChooser.getFileFilter();
    if (fileFilter instanceof FileNameExtensionFilter && ! fileFilter.accept(file)) {
      // if the filter doesn't accept the filename, that must be because it doesn't have the correct extension
      // so change the extension to the first extension offered by the filter.
      FileNameExtensionFilter fileNameExtensionFilter = (FileNameExtensionFilter) fileFilter;
      String extension = fileNameExtensionFilter.getExtensions()[0];

      String newName = file.getName() + "." + extension;
      file = new File(file.getParent(), newName);

    }

    System.out.println("The selected file is: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still have to add the extension myself. I'm trying to create a MS Access database with the Jacksess Library.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to get the filefilter selected by the user after he presses the validating button of the JFileChooser and compare the filefilter description with the list of your extensions before initializing the file object with the specified extension in your code if there is a match. I don't know if you will understand me.

```
        Modelexcel model = new Modelexcel();
        JFileChooser selectFile = new JFileChooser();;
        File file;

     JButton btnExporterVersExcel = new JButton("Exporter vers Excel");
        btnExporterVersExcel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(selectFile.showDialog(null, "Exporter")==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            String extension=selectFile.getFileFilter().getDescription();
                            if(extension.contains("(*.xlsx)")) {
                                file= new File(selectFile.getSelectedFile()+".xlsx");
                            }else if(extension.contains("(*.xls)")){
                                file= new File(selectFile.getSelectedFile()+".xls");
                            }
                            if(file.getName().endsWith("xls") || 
        file.getName().endsWith("xlsx")) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, model.Export(file, table));
                            }else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Format invalid");
                            }
                        }
}
        });
```

This is a fragment of my code to save files in ".xls" and ".xlsx" formats. Hope a look through it will help you